# Pandas GroupBy sum concatenates numbers instead of summing them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

When I use the following code:

```
    print(self.df.groupby(by=[2])[3].agg(['sum']))
```

On the following Dataframe:

```
            0    1        2        3       4     5     6     7
0          15  LCU   Test 1   308.02  170703  ALCU  4868  MS10
1          16  LCU   Test 2   127.37  170703  ALCU  4868  MS10
```

The sum function is not completed correctly because the value column (col 3) returns a concatenated string of the values (308.02127.37) instead of maintaining the integrity of the individual values to allow operation.

Comment: can't reproduce the behaviour you mentioned. Furthermore I get errors using you code (after removing the self-part)

Comment: Seems like your column 3 type is a string instead of a float, try casting it

Comment: It will be much better if you provide more rows of the dataframe to use groupby.

Comment: How did you load in your dataframe? Did you use `dtype=str`?

Comment: Deb, thank  you. I believe that may be the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like your 3rd column is a string. Did you load in your dataframe using `dtype=str`?

Furthermore, try not to hardcode your columns. You can use `.astype` or `pd.to_numeric` to cast and then apply `sum`:

```
self.df.groupby(self.df.columns[2])[self.df.columns[3]].agg(
    lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce').sum()
)
```

Or

```
self.df.groupby(self.df.columns[2])[self.df.columns[3]].agg(
    lambda x: x.astype(float).sum()
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I did this a different way, but will try each option to see what works best. The problem was that the column was not numeric.